# BufferedWriter not writing String Correctly

Tags: java, character-encoding, bufferedwriter

So I've got a program that talks to a database via telnet and previously I had it printing responses to the console, System.out.println(). Now I'm modifying my program so that it writes the responses to a file so I can run the program as a service/daemon. However, when using BufferedWriter, I don't get English. the preview of the file in File Explorer reads correctly but when I open the file in notepad or Sublime Text 2 I get this odd combination of digits. Here's my code and what the file should say as opposed to what I get when I open my file.

```
private static void logon() throws IOException {
    bout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/mnt/javaprograms/ServerConsole/log.txt"), "UTF-8"));

    String loginString = "JAVA-TRANS\n";
    byte[] logon = loginString.getBytes();
    out.write(logon);
    out.flush();
    out.write(logon);
    out.flush();
    response = in.readLine();
    bout.write(response);
    bout.flush();
    while (!response.contains("OK")) {
        response = in.readLine();
        bout.write(response);
        bout.flush();
    }
    bout.flush();
    bout.close();
}
```

File Explorer previews:

> Welcome to the mvBASE telnet server.You are connected to line 54 on
>   MILL6JAVA-TRANS

Opened file reads:

```
5765 6c63 6f6d 6520 746f 2074 6865 206d
7642 4153 4520 7465 6c6e 6574 2073 6572
7665 722e 596f 7520 6172 6520 636f 6e6e
6563 7465 6420 746f 206c 696e 6520 3534
206f 6e20 4d49 4c4c 364a 4156 412d 5452
414e 5300 4f4b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, your text editor is setup to display the hex representation of the underlying bytes. You'll have to change it to display textual representation in the appropriate character set.

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String text = "Welcome to the mvBASE telnet server.You are connected to line 54 on MILL6JAVA-TRANS";
    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int space = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b));
        space++;
        if (space == 16) {
            System.out.println();
            space = 0;
        } else if (space % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
5765 6c63 6f6d 6520 746f 2074 6865 206d 
7642 4153 4520 7465 6c6e 6574 2073 6572 
7665 722e 596f 7520 6172 6520 636f 6e6e 
6563 7465 6420 746f 206c 696e 6520 3534 
206f 6e20 4d49 4c4c 364a 4156 412d 5452 
414e 53
```

which is what you see (+/- 3 chars).

Comment: I edited my text editor (Sublime Text 2) to not show the hex. I thought there might have been something I was doing wrong since both ST2 and Windows Notepad showed the hex